# What are some good use cases for the JS WeakSet?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6, weakmap

Both the JavaScript [`WeakSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) and [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) ES2015 standard built-in objects are JS structures with which I have little experience using. I know that the *weak* part of `WeakMap`/`WeakSet` refers to references in those objects being held weakly. But what are some good scenarios in which these objects (particularly the `WeakSet`) are ideal to use?